# How do I get simple product name of configurable into checkout Order summary?

Tags: magento2, checkout, configurable-product

I need to get the simple product name of configurable into checkout order summary. So I need to know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Override __getTotalsData()__ function from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php`. Here you can change item array.

Comment: I override as below. But it will display same simple product name when i choose other option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write a small extension for that.

1.app/code/Vendor/Namespace/etc/module.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"> 
     <module name="Vendor_Namespace" setup_version="1.0.0">
     </module>
   </config>
```

2.app/code/Vendor/Namespace/etc/di.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"> 
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
      </type>
    </config>
```

3. app/code/Vendor/Namespace/Plugin/ConfigProviderPlugin.php

```
   <?php
       namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin;
         class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
           {
             public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
               {
                 $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
                 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();          

                 for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

                  $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
                  $quoteNext = ($quoteId + 1);

                  $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteNext);
                  $simpleProName = $quote->getName();

                  $items[$i]['childname'] = $simpleProName;
                }
                 $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
                 return $result;
               }

           }
```

4.app/code/Vendor/Namespace/registration.php

```
      <?php
         \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
            \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
              'Vendor_Namespace',
                __DIR__
               );
```

5.Copy the file (details.html) from below path for your theme.

```
 vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html
```

And then Replace the

```
 <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name">
```

by

```
 <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.childname">
```

Thanks. Sejal Shah. I refer your extension to do this.

Comment: In next tab you click for payment and review section again you'll see main product name. Can  you please see it.

Comment: I need to get the simple product name of configurable into a cart, checkout Order summary, mini-cart and also order and email template. So I need to know how to do it?

Comment: In next tab you click for payment and review section again you'll see main product name, Anyone gets the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hasitha Anuruddha for your solution.
There's only one problem I've faced with your plugin.

In the provided solution the `childname` always is set as the name of the next quote item, unless if the item is a configurable product or not.
To avoid this, I've introduced a check if the `parentItemId` of the "child" quote item matches the `itemId` of the original quote item.

Further I've cleaned the usage of the object manager in favor of dependency injection.

Update version for `app/code/Vendor/Namespace/Plugin/ConfigProviderPlugin.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
     */
    private $quoteItem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->quoteItem = $quoteItem;

        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
        array $result
    ) {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
            $originalQuoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $nextQuoteId = ($originalQuoteId + 1);
            $nextQuote = $this->quoteItem->load($nextQuoteId);

            if ($nextQuote->getParentItemId() === $originalQuoteId) {
                $productName = $nextQuote->getName();
            } else {
                $productName = $items[$i]['name'];
            }

            $items[$i]['childname'] = $productName;
        }
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to get the simple product name of configurable into a cart, checkout Order summary, mini-cart and also order and email template. So I need to know how to do it?

Comment: This looks useful. Was this ever compiled into a module?

Answer (score 0):

If the name is not reflecting on next step of checkout(on payment page), please extend

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js
```

add the following code there :

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} quoteItem
         * @return {String}
         */
        getValue: function (quoteItem) {
            return quoteItem.name;
        },

        getName: function(quoteItem) {
            var totalsData = window.checkoutConfig.totalsData;
            var productName = '';
            totalsData['items'].forEach(function(item) {
                if(parseInt(quoteItem) === parseInt(item['item_id'])){
                    productName = item['childname'];
                }
            });
            return productName;
        }
    });
});
```

and change your HTML file :

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html
```

and change this piece of code from

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

to

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="html: getName($parent.item_id)"></strong>
```

If it works, please help to upvote my answer.