# How do I set simple product name instead of configurable into cart,checkout Order summary , mini-cart and also order and email in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, cart, magento2.2.6

I already used this answer but this answer is just half answer to my question-
 [How do I get simple product name of configurable into checkout Order summary?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207365/how-do-i-get-simple-product-name-of-configurable-into-checkout-order-summary)

I need to get the simple product name of configurable into a cart, checkout Order summary, mini-cart and also order and email template. So I need to know how to do it?

Comment: did you ever work this out?

Comment: no still not....

Comment: i found out =P https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105303/how-to-add-simple-product-to-cart-instead-of-configurable-product/258267#258267

Comment: your answer is little bit diffrenet. I want to add a configurable product but just name is simple product

Comment: your code in added simple product into cart

Comment: heyyy.. I need the same, have you found the solution ?

Comment: Also looking for a good solution to this.